# two questions about rectangle and canvas in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, canvas, resize

I have a rectangle on canvas. I can already moving this object using with mouse, but I can't find how can I resize it in runtime using mouse too? 
And second question, how can I programatically check positions of each objects (e.g rectangles) on the canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-sizing a rectangle using the mouse can be pretty involved. Basically you can listen for mouse-down, mouse-up, and mouse-move events which would allow you to adjust the width and height of it programmatically.

To move a rectangle within the canvas, try the following concept:

double x = Canvas.GetLeft(this.myRectangle);
x += 100;
Canvas.SetLeft(this.myRectangle, x);

Answer (score 1):

Most people use a [Thumb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb.aspx). [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749252.aspx) is an msdn article that shows you how to use a thumb to resize a canvas. The same principles can be applied to your rectangle.